# how to push local notification even the app is killed so it work in the background?

Tags: flutter

in the main i'm checking if a data in shared preferences is true the launch a local notification
it work fine if the app is running
but if it killed, never work
i need a something like reminder so it work in the background
work when a certain time comes , it push notification
i tried to use flutter_isolate with Flutter_startup
but didn't work
this is the code i used

```
import 'package:flutter_isolate/flutter_isolate.dart';
import 'package:flutter_startup/flutter_startup.dart';
//this code in the package of flutter_isolate and do't understand it
void isolate2(String arg) async {
  FlutterStartup.startupReason.then((reason) {
  });
 }
 //also this but the timer is mine
 void isolate1(String arg) async {
 final isolate = await FlutterIsolate.spawn(isolate2, "hello2");
 SharedPreferences preferences = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
 FlutterStartup.startupReason.then((reason) {
 });
 Timer.periodic(Duration(seconds: 10), (timer) {
   log(">>>> inside timer");
   if (preferences.getString("randomtime") != null) {
    if (preferences.getString("randomtime") == "true") {
      NotificationApi.showNotification(
      body: "this is body",
      id: 3,
      payload: "this is payload",
      title: "this is title",
      );
     }
   }
 });
 }

 void main() async {
 WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
 await GetStorage.init();
 SharedPreferences preferences = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
 final isolate = await FlutterIsolate.spawn(isolate1, "hello");
 Timer.periodic(Duration(seconds: 10), (timer) => isolate.resume());


 runApp(MyApp());
 }
```

this package didn't help me to run the app in the background

Answer (score 0):

You may wanna try to use one of the following packages for local Push Notifications:

- https://pub.dev/packages/awesome_notifications
- https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_local_notifications

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

i solved it when add
NotificationApi.init();
before timer periodic

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).